# Equal height of columns within a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create the following Bootsrap design:

I have 2 parts, col-lg-8 and col-lg-4.
3 text boxes at one side (col-lg-8) and 3 select control plus one textbox at the other side (col-lg-4). The height of both divs col-lg-8 and col-lg-4 should be the same.

How can we achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control    ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <form role="form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" >
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" >
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control"  >
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control-sm">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bootstrap class called "row-eq-height". If we use this class in the row then the columns within that will be of same height.

Here in your code you have to use the class row-eq-height in the most outer row. Your modified code is this :

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">

            <input class="form-control    ">

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <input class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" >
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
<div class="col-lg-4">

    <form role="form">

      <div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group">

            <select class="form-control" >
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
                 <div class="form-group">

            <select class="form-control" >
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
                 <div class="form-group">

            <select class="form-control"  >
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control-sm">
        </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
```